# MySQL check case where a date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, time

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT `date_joined`, `date_last_joined` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = "mary"
```

The `date_last_joined` column is currently `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for all users. It's then updated to the current date next time they log in.

So my question is, how would I return the `date_joined` if `date_last_joined` is  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, and `date_last_joined` if it isn't? Is this possible in a MySQL query?

The reasons for this are that returning `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in a Java prepared MySQL query causes all sorts of issues.

Comment: Just run your query because it will return correct result

Comment: You shoudld accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IF` flow control operator:

```
SELECT IF(`users`.`date_last_joined` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
          `users`.`date_joined`, `users`.`date_last_joined`) AS `join_date`
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.`name` = 'mary'
```

Comment: @user3420034 Not necessarily, depends on what MySQL driver implementation you're using and what language. In PHP, using `PDO` you could retrieve it like this: `$join_date = $sth->fetchColumn();`

Comment: @user3420034 Then it would be easier to alias it like you suggested: `AS \`join_date\``